# How to create a recurring event in outlook using deeplink

Tags: outlook, deep-linking

On my website I have button "Add To Calendar". When user is clicking on the button, I am opening a new browser window and passing following URL:

https://outlook.office.com/calendar/deeplink/compose?subject=Intermit+Opportunity&body=%3cp%3e%c2%a0%3c%2fp%3e%0d%0a%0d%0a%3cp%3e%c2%a0%3c%2fp%3e%0d%0a&startdt=2023-12-05T08:00:00&enddt=2023-12-05T09:00:00&location=Somewhere+Else&path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose&rru=addevent&allday=False

It is displaying outlook event creation screen with all the event details pre-populated. User can click on Save button and it will create the event on user's calendar. Everything is working fine.

My problem is that I have another event which is a recurring/repeated event. I am not able to figure out how can I pass the recurrence information in the deeplink, like I am passing other event details.

Any idea how we can pass that information in deeplink?

I tried passing various parameters like RRULE etc. but nothing worked.